# cannot static file through static url using django.test.client

Tags: python, django, python-unittest, django-unittest

## 1.env

- python : 3.8.14
- django version : '4.2.4'

## 2.Purpose

- Make sure that the static file is saved
- Make sure that the static file can be accessed from the web browser

## 3.Issue

The problem is that after running `django server`, the `static file` can be accessed through `url`, but not in the `unitest environment`.

For example, suppose a file is stored in the following path

```
'MAPPER  #<- project dir  
 |-datasets #<-app name
    |-static
       |-datasets
          |-images
             |-Recursion Cellular Image Classification.jpeg
```

### 3.1 Access the browser after running the server

- enter the following path into the browser to confirm that it works well.
  http://localhost:8000/static/datasets/static/datasets/images/Recursion Cellular Image Classification.jpeg

### 3.2 unittest

- get a 404 status code. and cannot get the image file

```py
from django.test import Client
client = Client()
res_redirect = self.client.get(res.url)
```

## 4. try

I tried using `requests.get` , but i didn't work
`requests.get(http://localhost:8000/static/datasets/static/datasets/images/Recursion Cellular Image Classification.jpeg)`

## 5. Question

SO this is my question, how can i access file through url in `unittest env`

Comment: Try replacing spaces with underscore in filename and check.

Comment: tks reply , but it didn't work.

Comment: is allow setting.py static files ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to URL encode to properly handle the spaces in the URL.  a [space] character is %20, eg,

```
requests.get(
    'http://localhost:8000/static/datasets/static/datasets/images/Recursion%20Cellular%20Image%20Classification.jpeg'
)
```

(Don't forget the quotes)

However, seeing as you are working with a property or field, `res.url` you'll need to pass it to a function to urlEncode it. As you are already using `requests` you can use:

```
#safe argument allows the / and : in http://localhost:80000 to be unencoded
encoded_url = requests.utils.quote(res.url, safe="/:")

requests.get(encoded_url)
```